# How to lock saving files through extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Before saving the file, I have to write the file to an external resource. If the external resource is not available, the file should not be saved. I tried to use the event `onWillSaveTextDocument: Event<TextDocumentWillSaveEvent>`. But it does not allow to mark saving changes in the file.

Comment: You need to give us some code and show where you have the problem

Comment: You want to save a file to two locations? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Yes, and if I can not save the file on a remote server, cancel the save locally